# Can't pin Gnome Terminal to plank in Fedora

Tags: fedora, plank

I just installed plank in Fedora 24. Normally, we can pin an item to the dock by right clicking and selecting `Keep in Dock`. For other applications I can do this. But for the gnome terminal, I won't get a `Keep in Dock` option. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6):

Create a file called `org.gnome.Terminal.dockitem` in `~/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/`

Paste the following in that file and save.

```
[PlankItemsDockItemPreferences]
Launcher=file:///usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Terminal.desktop
```

Restart Plank and your Terminal should appear.

It creates another icon when you launch, if I figure that out I will update my Answer. Other Terminals seem to behave properly. I'm using Terminator and had no issues pinning it to Plank

Comment: Thanks. Yep I also came this far but the problem is, it creates a new icon when I launch the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

#### Also make sure, that in Plank Settings → Behaviour Tab → Lock Icons is `OFF`.

I stumbled over this being `ON` multiple times for whatever reason.
(otherwise, any `.docktitem` file copied to the launchers folder is instantly deleted agais. Thus also no undermining by terminal means.)

Comment: Great tip! I had already tried restarting and even reinstalling plank but nothing worked.

Answer (score -1):

Edit the relevant .desktop file:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Terminal.desktop
```

Then comment out the line

```
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity
```

so that it looks like this:

```
#OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity
```